Fiori app page is blank after cache clearing
I have changed code in BSP application controller.js for particular input field but changes not reflected in fiori app therefore executed /UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE for cache clearing which I assumed possible cause of problem but after execution of report /UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE Fiori app page is blank at all,no content,fields,texts etc visible/appearing .
How it is possible bring back all fiori page content?
executed Standard /UI5/APP_INDEX_CALCULATE  for cache clearing but made entire fiori app page blank.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
